# User uploads image to server and image is set to background-image of div

Tags: html, ajax, image, background, upload

Im looking for a super simple way to allow a user to upload an image to my server and then set that uploaded image the background-image tag of a div. I can't use the methods that just display a local file it needs to be actually uploaded to my server.

I've messed with a simple script like this but of course the page changes when pressing submit. I need it stay on the html page and change the div. Any help appreciated!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="winupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

<div id="mainimage" style="background-color:#cccccc;width:300px;height:300px;">test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

HTML Above and PHP below

```
    <?php
$target_dir = "winups/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Check if file already exists
//if (file_exists($target_file)) {
//    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
//    $uploadOk = 0;
//}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $changable_data["js_script"] = 'document.getElementById("mainimage").style.backgroundImage = "url('. basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). ')";';
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just FYI the reason I can't do local is because I will be using canvas to save the image later and local doesn't seem to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

doing this securely is, unfortunately, not all that `simple`. the easiest way to embed an image after upload, is to serve it as inline base64 (it use more ram and bandwidth than serving it over an url, but you wanted it `simple`, and the base64 method avoids problems like html encoding the final savename, making sure the web server has permissions to the upload folder, and problems with the save folder not being reachable from the web root folder). as a rule of thumb, you should not let hackers decide the actual save filename on your server (what happens if the hackers make the filename `../../../../../etc/passwd\x00.jpg` ? or `/srv/http/default/evil_script.php\x00.jpg` ? or `<script>evil_javascript();</script>.jpg` ? ), but since you want it `simple`, you can get away with validating that the name doesn't contain any dangerous characters (regex comes in handy here), the alternative is to save the user(/hacker-supplied?) filename in a database, and the on-disk file under some other name (perhaps set the on-disk filename as the metadata db's unique key for this file? that's what i usually do, but that is not `simple`). as for `I need it stay on the html page and change the div` - this is possible without a refresh through javascript, but not necessary, and less `simple`, you can make do with a plain old dynamic php page, instead of the javascript/XMLHttpRequest route here, try:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
$uploadOk = 0;
if (! empty ( $_FILES ['fileToUpload'] )) {
    $target_dir = "winups/";
    $name = $_FILES ['fileToUpload'] ['name'];
    if (! preg_match ( '/^[[:alnum:][:space:]\_\.\-]{4,100}$/ui', $name )) {
        http_response_code ( 400 );
        die ( "illegal filename detected. for security reasons, the filename must match the regex /^[[:alnum:][:space:]\_\.\-]{4,100}$/ui" );
    }
    $imageFileType = strtolower ( pathinfo ( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
    $extensionWhitelist = array (
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'png',
            'gif',
            'bmp' 
    );
    if (! in_array ( $imageFileType, $extensionWhitelist, true )) {
        http_response_code ( 400 );
        die ( "Sorry, only allowed image types are: " . htmlentities ( implode ( ', ', $extensionWhitelist ) ) );
    }
    if (false === getimagesize ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"] )) {
        http_response_code ( 400 );
        die ( "image is corrupted" );
    }
    // ok, the image passed the security checks.

    $target_file = $target_dir . $name;
    // now to find an unique filename
    // OPTIMIZEME, excessive syscalls will be cpu-expensive and slow, DoS vector, use glob() or some limit lower than PHP_INT_MAX ? 
    if (file_exists ( $target_file )) {
        $success = false;
        for($i = 2; $i < PHP_INT_MAX; ++ $i) {
            if (! file_exists ( "$i." . $target_file )) {
                $success = true;
                $target_file = "$i." . $target_file;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (! $success) {
            http_response_code ( 500 );
            die ( "too many duplicates of this filename! (" . PHP_INT_MAX . " duplicates!)" );
        }
    }
    $uploadOk = 1;

    if (! move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"], $target_file )) {
        http_response_code ( 500 );
        die ( "Sorry, an internal server error while saving your file" );
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="?" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"
            id="fileToUpload"> <input type="submit" value="Upload Image"
            name="submit">
    </form>
<?php
if ($uploadOk) {
    echo "The file " . htmlentities ( $name ) . " has been uploaded.";
    echo '<div id="mainimage" style="background-color: #cccccc; width: 300px; height: 300px;"><img src="data:image/' . $imageFileType . ';base64,' . base64_encode ( file_get_contents ( $target_file ) ) . '" /></div>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```